# VSC align markdown lists in Editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-align

I'm new to Visual Code Studio, and mainly use it for writing in markdown.

When making lists in Editor, is it possible that they align when words wrap.
Currently, the words on the next line of a list don't left align. For example:

[image: example list here]

Ideally, the new line words (`particular`, `if`, `full`) align with the word 'Civility' (as you would see in a preview view).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think indent is context aware in vscode.

The best thing you can do is to use indent size equal `2` and a changing `wrappingIndent`:

```js
"[markdown]": {
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "editor.wrappingIndent": "indent",
  "editor.tabSize": 2
},
```

But it would also work for all indents (not just in lists).

Comment: Thanks.  I did try that. But it ends up indenting the second line of regular paragraphs. Or is there a setting I'm missing to prevent that too?

Comment: No. There is no setting that does that.